# kdb.py file contains an error

Tags: python, kdb

I want to run KDB using python and downloaded the kdb.py from

https://bitbucket.org/halotis/qpy/

However, I have an error on line `k = 86400000L * 10957`:

```
# 86400000 is number of milliseconds in a day
# 10957 is days offset between UNIX Epoch and kdb Epoch

k = 86400000L * 10957
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Anyone help me please? 
Thanks!

============================================
[image]

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Please find attached screenshot

Comment: Post error text as text. Why do you have an uppercase `L` inside a decimal number?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using Python 3. Drop the suffix "L", it doesn't make a difference for integers. It was different in Python 2.x, but now it makes a syntax error.

See Python 2 docs: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals

and Python 3 docs:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals